# Use Custom object type in DropDownListFor - MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

`@Html.DropDownListFor` requires a List of SelectListItem. Is there a way to use a custom object here instead of select list item and tell the drop down list which properties of the custom object to use for the value and text? Or is there an easy way to translate my customer object to a SelectListItem?

I have a Status object:
public string StatusCode {get;set;}
public string StatusCodeDescription {get;set;}

So right now I would have to write a for loop to translate a Status to a SelectListItem for all my Lists... This just seems like there needs to be an easier way...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> @Html.DropDownListFor requires a List of SelectListItem. Is there a
>   way to use a custom object here instead of select list item and tell
>   the drop down list which properties of the custom object to use for
>   the value and text?

You could use the [`SelectList constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) taking 3 arguments: an `IEnumerable<T>` and 2 strings representing the names of the value and text properties of the custom type:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedStatusCode, 
    new SelectList(
        Model.Satuses, 
        "StatusCode",  
        "StatusCodeDescription"
    )
)
```

In this example we assume that `Model.Satuses` is a property of type `IEnumerable<StatusViewModel>` where `StatusViewModel` contains at least 2 properties to bind the respectively the value and the text of the dropdown:

```
public class StatusViewModel
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; } 
    public string StatusCodeDescription { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that answers the question. In general, I understand how lamda expressions work, but I'm confused on this one. `x => x.SelectedStatusCode` What is this value is stored at: `Model.Application.SelectedStatusCode`?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to say, how does the view know what `x` is? How does it know where in the model the value `x.SelectedStatusCode` refers to? Is it assumed that this value is in the same location as `Model.SelectedStatusCode`?

Comment: This is coming from the model you declared at the top of your view: `@model SomeViewModel`. Once you do that you could use strongly typed Html helpers which are taking a lambda expression where the parameter is the model. The DropDownListFor helper is defined like this: `DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, Tproperty>> expression)` and since you have a strongly typed view, the generic parameters are inferred by the compiler.

Comment: Ok, so then as I understand it, if the `SelectedStatusCode` value was located at `Model.Application.SelectedStatusCode` then I would use `x => x.Application.SelectedStatusCode` as the first parameter`. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much... too bad this info is not in the MS documentation :)

Comment: Just as another thought? Will this automatically select the option in the SelectList that corrisponds to the current value of SelectedStatusCode, assuming Selected Status Code is populated in the Model when the view executes?

Comment: It depends on the navigation context. IIRC if you have only one level it will work (for example `x => x.SelectedStatusCode`). But if you have deeper nesting (like `x => x.Application.SelectedStatusCode`) you might need to pass the value as fourth argument of the `SelectList` constructor even if you already specified it in the lambda expression: `new SelectList(Model.Satuses, "StatusCode",  "StatusCodeDescription", Model.Application.SelectedStatusCode)`. Can't remember exactly about this though, don't take my word for granted. Check it out.